# Mapbox tile is not being added to leaflet.js map?

Tags: google-maps, leaflet, mapbox

I am trying to add a Mapbox tile to my project using leaflet.js. I wrote the code like following:

```
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/johirbuet.l2ohahk4/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
maxZoom: 18
}).addTo(map);
```

But I am getting error and no map is showing in the page. Whats the problem with this code? I followed the documentation. In may code MapID: johirbuet.l2ohahk4

Comment: Did you add var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13); before that? and verify you have a map div?

Comment: Acutally it looks like your mapbox is restricting it. Its returning a 401 unauthorized. Verify you have the mapbox setting set up to allow for you to access it.

Comment: Yes I have var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);  and also a div with id 'map'

Comment: How can i do that setting i nmapbox?

Comment: Should your title be "leaflet.**js**", not "leaflet.ja"?

Comment: yes. it should be leaflet.js. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add your token to the request otherwise you'll get 404:

> {"message":"Not Authorized - No Token"}

Correct code:

```
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{mapId}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={token}', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
    subdomains: ['a','b','c','d'],
    mapId: 'myMapId',
    token: 'myUserToken'
});
```